# Spring Boot application in Docker Container with MySQL in Host

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile

I have a `Spring Boot` application that I'm planning to run on a `Docker` container and to test this application I'm connection to `MySQL` on my host machine. To do that I have a property in my `application.properties` as below

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/flexapp`

Now when I do `./mvnw install dockerfile:build` it tried to build the application before building the `Docker image`. While it's building it says

`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: host.docker.internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Obviously it's not able to resolve `host.docker.internal`.

How do I connect my `Spring Boot` application in `Docker` container to the `MySql` Instance in my host machine? I googled and tried a lot of solution but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there are some tests being executed that are trying to connect to the database. Those tests will fail due to the unablity to resolve `host.docker.internal`.

The standard solution is to externalize configuration using one of methods that spring boot provides: [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

In particular, one way is to set the `spring.datasource.url` to point to localhost inside application.properties and to override it inside the Dockerfile by passing

```
--spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/flexapp
```

To the Entrypoint or CMD instruction inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: You are correct. Before `Docker` process kicks in, `maven build` process get's executed which does not understand `host.docker.internal`. I will try what you mentioned. Thanks! I wish `Docker` provided native way to build `Spring Boot` applications

Comment: Could you add an example to pass the datasource url to entrypoint in dockerfile?