# how does containered springboot image connect itself to mysql5.7 which runs locally?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I have written a very simple demo project, you can download it by clicking [here](https://d613.top/filebedcc/static/d874ca730b814f3ba5bb90d67.zip).

The above java project will be containerized as an docker image. But it needs to connect to the local mysql database which is not containerized.

I tried changing the value of `spring.datasource.url` from `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false` to `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.105:3306/db?characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false` in the `application.yaml`. This change seems to bring success.

so I Change the value of `spring.datasource.url` back to the original and tried `docker run --network=host .....`,but this didn't success.. why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you running your demo app in linux m/c ? The host networking (`network=host`) only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server. You can check https://docs.docker.com/network/host/ for details

Comment: @Sachin Thank you very much, it runs in windows.... so is there a method for app in windows? Thanks.

Comment: cant you use the docker host ip in your properties file ? From the above description you have mentioned it works. you could also try `host.docker.internal` as mentioned in documentation - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/. you can also refer to similar question in SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017473/spring-boot-application-in-docker-container-with-mysql-in-host, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach